# Xamarin.Forms: Android api calls are not visible in the proxy server

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, charles-proxy, network-traffic

I'm working on an existing **Xamarin.Forms app** to fix some issues on Android.

To investigate, I would like to be able to see the traffic from the app with a proxy server like [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/welcome/).

The traffic is is well visible on iPhone, whereas it not visible at all on Android: I don't see any call after a login or a sync...

I've tried to configure the Android side by adding the **network_security_config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
     <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
   </base-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
            <certificates src="user" />
            <!-- Trust preinstalled CAs -->
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Then I've updated the **AndroidManifext.xml** to enable this file:

```
<application android:label="XXX" android:allowBackup="false" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

But the result is still the same: I don't see any call in my proxy server tool...

***Is there anything else I could check to see the traffic on Android?***

Comment: have you looked at the different options for HTTP client in the Android project settings?

Comment: Hello @Jason the options are to "default" for the "HttpClient implementation" and the "SSL/TLS implementation".